# Pass service params to docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  strongloop:
    image: node:5.11-onbuild
    links:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.3
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf
```

Now I need to start the mongodb service with the flag `-f /etc/mongo.conf` and parallel starts the strongloop service and link them. Until now I did this with `docker-compose up` because I didn't need some flags.

How can I pass this flag to `docker-compose up`?

Or is there an other command that links the container and where I can pass some params to the specific service?

Edit:

`docker-compose up mongodb -f /etc/mongo.conf strongloop` returns `ERROR: No such service: -f`

`docker-compose up "mongodb -f /etc/mongo.conf" strongloop`
returns `ERROR: No such service: mongodb -f /etc/mongo.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change docker-compose.yml as below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  strongloop:
    image: node:5.11-onbuild
    links:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.3
    command: mongod -f /etc/mongo.conf
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf
```

After that, just run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks! Correct command would be `mongod -f /etc/mongo.conf` (mongod not mongodb)